# React setState not called when mutating with react query

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

I have a parent component where I do api fetching with react query:

```
export default () => {
    const { caseId } = useCaseProvider();
    const { api } = useMockApi();
    const { data: caseData, refetch, isRefetching } = api.getCasaData(caseId);
    const mutation = api.postCaseData(caseId);

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader size="3xlarge" title="loading..." />}>
            <CaseForm
                caseData={caseData}
                refetch={refetch}
                isRefetching={isRefetching}
                mutation={mutation}
            />
        </Suspense>
    );
};
```

And in the CaseForm component since I have button for both save and submit I need to set loading states for both of them depending on which one was clicked. I thought of setting flags with `useState` hook for that:

```
const CaseForm = ({ caseData, refetch, isRefetching, mutation }) => {
    const { caseFormValues, setCaseFormValues, setActiveStep } = useCaseProvider();
    const initialValues = caseFormValues ?? createInitialValues(caseData);
    const [isSaving, setIsSaving] = useState(false);
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

const onSave = async () => {
    setIsSaving(true);
    await save();
    setIsSaving(false);
};

const save = async () => {
    await mutation.mutate({ ...caseData, ...getValues() });
    setCaseFormValues(getValues());
};

const onSubmit = async () => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    await save();
    setIsSubmitting(false);
    setActiveStep(STEPS[Stepper.INCOME]);
};
```

But, when I click on any of these buttons both isSubmitting and isSaving always remain `false`. What am I doing wrong here, how can I fix this?

Comment: I think you missed something since you are not calling onSave

Comment: what do you mean by  when I click on any of these buttons both isSubmitting and isSaving always remain false ?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `mutation.mutate` along with `await`, but this is not an async function. You should be using `mutation.mutateAsync` that you can await, these are two different functions and only `mutateAsync` returns a Promise.

When it's used like this, `setIsSaving(true)` and `setIsSaving(false)` is called in quick succession, either as a microtask or a next tick (not sure without checking) and you don't see the result of the render-in between. Maybe react even manages to batch the updates?

---

Sidenote:

The mutation itself has `mutation.isLoading`, so the ultimate question is why duplicate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your `save()` function is `async`, but you do not `await` it. The consequence is that the sequence during `onSave()` will set the `isSaving` value back to false right away.

Since there was no change in the next render (`isSaving` having been changed from `false` -> `true` -> `false`, no changes are to be observed on the `isSaving` value.

The fix would be to `await` the `save()` function, or reset the variable after the `await`.

Possible fix

```
const onSave = async () => {
        setIsSaving(true);
        await save();
        setIsSaving(false);
    };
```

Or

```
const onSave = () => {
        setIsSaving(true);
        save();
    };

    const save = async () => {
        await mutation.mutate({ ...caseData, ...getValues() });
        setCaseFormValues(getValues());
        setIsSaving(false);
    };
```

Or even

```
const onSave = () => {
        setIsSaving(true);
        save().then(() => setIsSaving(false));
    };
```

The same logic applied to the `onSubmit()`.

Comment: I have tried with that too, it didn't work

Comment: Did you log the value of the variables to check if they change at some point? Does `CaseForm` return a JSX component inside a `.jsx` file? Maybe try to add a `await sleep(5000)` to slow down the process and check what happens